# How to show an alert when user is trying to go in background mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a simple alert dialog box when user push an app to background and ask something like `Are you sure?` before losing all the important information on that page. I am using multi-screen form to get user data and don't want to break the flow so a simple message would help.

I am trying to achieve this with `WidgetsBindingObserver` and `AppLifecycleState` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('paused');
        AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Are you sure?'),
        );
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

`Paused` is getting print so the functionality is working fine, now I need some way to restrict this with Alert Dialog box or any other way.

Comment: You can't do something like that, All you can do handle backpressed button callback, for home button it will not work

Comment: If you want to handle back button functionality, I can post the answer for it

Comment: Okay. For the back button, `willPopScope` can work but that's not what I need here.

Comment: What you **want** would lead to extremely annoying user experience, just think of the number of apps that would abuse this (ex: here is advert and you are gonna watch it for full two minutes no matter what you press on your phone). What you **need**  is to save that page state so it can be rebuilt later and the user can continue without having to fill anything again.